# Rebase and changing branch is including all merged commits in pull request

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I'm coming from a SVN background. I've forked and branched a git repository. Then I changed the branch (let's call it `my-branch`), committed, pushed and sent a Pull Request.

It happens that the upstream repository has been changed and my PR became invalid due to conflicts generated by the master changes.

**How should I proceed to rebase my branch to solve the conflicts and update the PR?**

I tried fetching changes from upstream master to local master then rebasing my branch to local master:

```git
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push origin master
git checkout my-branch
git rebase master
```

The problem is that when I resolved the conflicts and committed/pushed the changes, all commits from upstream are also being included in the PR, as if I have made these changes. So, again, **how should I proceed to really "rebase" my branch and PR, so I can safely change and commit to the PR only the files I've changed?**

Comment: When you say that `upstream/master` has been changed, **in what way has it changed exactly**?  Does it have new commits that it previously didn't have?  Or did someone `rebase` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have these conventions :

- `upstream` is the remote name of the forked project
- `origin` is the remote name of your github fork

Here's the correct worflow to update a feature branch with new commits from `upstream/master` :

- `git checkout my-branch` // Switch onto your feature branch
- `git fetch --all` // Fetch new commits from all your declared remotes
- `git rebase upstream/master` // Rebase your feature branch onto the last commit of upstream/master
- `git push -f origin my-branch` // Overwrite your remote `my-branch` (mandatory since a rebase rewrites commits)

Your PR should be updated with the new commits of `my-branch`

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But now I'm a bit curious. The workflow I tried is similar to yours, which are the key differences? What caused all previous commits to be included as if I had made then in the PR?